# CD doesn't appear on Desktop

Tags: cd-burning

Whenever I insert a CD in my external burner/reader, it does not appear on my Desktop. Therefore I cannot copy to it. I cannot eject it either without restarting my computer and holding the option key. I have set up the CD/DVD in the preferences.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Open Finder preferences, click on General tab and see if "CDs, DVDs and iPods" is checked under "Show these items on the desktop:"

Comment: In order to get the help you need, you will need to help us. Please provide the model and OS version of your Mac (Apple Menu > About This Mac) and the make and model of your external drive and how you are hooking it up to your mac (USB? If so direct connect or through a hub?

Comment: Thanks Nimesh.  The CDs, DVDs and iPods is checked to show on desktop.  Not because I knew to do that but is was there by default.

Comment: Steve, I am using a new Macbook Pro  and using Mojave. The external drive is a Mac and I need to use a usb to thunderbolt adapter to connect.  The drive does work on my office Macbook Pro but that has High Sierra.  So, maybe it is the OS?